# Skip code when filters applied and returns no results VBA

Tags: vba, excel, filtering

I am using the below code to filter data as part of a much larger code however in some cases there may not be any results returned when the filters are applied. Alternatively If no results are returned I would like to skip part of the code.

Can anyone suggest the code I would need to use for this. (I'm guessing it would be an IF statement but unsure)

The code I am currently using is

```
Worksheets("DC Allocations Input").Activate
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Projects123"
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$9:$CT$382").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$9:$CT$382").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=OPP", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=RSK"
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$9:$CT$382").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I got that right, but you might be looking for jumps; https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/69whc95c.aspx Write `NAME:` into the line you wanna jump to and use `GoTo NAME` to skip the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an if statement with special cells visible like this:

```
Dim lngCnt As Long
On Error GoTo someplace 'you get an error if there are no visible cells, use it to skip to where you want
lngCnt = Range("$b$10:$CT$382").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count 'Note I'm not including the headings row, this will always be visible
On Error GoTo 0
'Put your code to run if there are results from the filter here
someplace:
'And the code you want to resume at here
```